# MySQL searching timestamp columns by date only

Tags: mysql

I am building out a query to search a table by a timestamp column value. An example of the format I am passing to the api is `2018-10-10`. The user has the ability to select a date range. Often times the date range start date is `2018-10-10` and end date is the same day, `2018-10-10`. The below doesn't seem to do the trick. What is the simplest way to accomplish this without having to specify the time? Obviously, I'd like to query for the entire day of 2018-10-10 from start to end of day.

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    contact
WHERE
    created_at >= '2018-10-10'
    AND created_at <= '2018-10-10';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `Timestamp` datatype will have `HH:MM:SS` (time) values also. While comparing a datetime with date, MySQL would automatically assume `00:00:00` as `HH:MM:SS` for the date value.

So, `2018-10-10 12:23:22` will not match the following condition: `created_at <= '2018-10-10'`; since it would be treated as: `2018-10-10 12:23:22 <= '2018-10-10 00:00:00`, which is **false**

To handle this, you can add one day to the date (**date_to** in the filter), and use `<` operator for range checking.

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    contact
WHERE
    created_at >= '2018-10-10'
    AND created_at < ('2018-10-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```